# Distributed computing using r

Tags: r

I am trying to build a system where I have the monthly sales data of all employees in my department for the past 1 year.

```
sales<-read.table(text="MONTH     Emp1    Emp2    Emp3 
           1                1000      1500      1100
           2                1200      1400      1600
           3                1500      1400      1600
           4                1300      1500      1400
           5                1500      1200      1200", header=T)
```

and so on till month 10

Through an algorithm, I have forecasted their future values and found the maximum percentage increase they can achieve.

```
threshold<-read.table(text="Employee     'Max Increment Possible'
Emp1                 200
Emp2                 220
Emp3                 300",header=T)
```

Now I am setting a target of 400 increase in my department but want to distribute it among my employees in the best possible way. Wondering if there is an existing package that can do this in R.

The output should be:
Employee      Incremental Value
Emp1            120
Emp1            140
Emp1            140

Comment: "Load-balancing" and "distributed computing" usually refer to managing how computer clusters work - you might want to edit your question to not use those terms. Also, can you give an example of your desired output? It doesn't seem clear at all. How would you measure "best"ness of a possible distribution of your 400 (units? percentage points?).

Comment: I would calculate best with percentage points

Comment: But what makes one distribution better than another? "Percentage points" does not answer that question.

Comment: with respect to the current month value how much more is the target value and what percentage of their Max Increment Possible is that. A uniform distribution of both will be the best algorithm